# Removing Commas In CSV so it does not show up when editing with Notepad

Tags: excel, csv

I need to have a padded file but value in cell A1 needs to be their. When i open with notepad i get this:

```
A,,,
TOM,JONES,50,LONDON
MARY,JANE,35,CHICAGO
```

is there a way to remove the ,,, from the CSV file permanently?

Comment: In Notepad you can replace ',' with an empty string by pressing CTRL+H

Comment: But when i open the file again they are repopulated

Comment: I would suggest opening the csv file in Excel, then use comma-delimited to remove the commas

Comment: perhaps save the file as .txt instead of .csv? As technically once you remove the commas, its no longer "comma separated values"

Comment: Do you want to remove only **trailing commas** ??

Comment: Hi all, Yes its just the trailing commas i want removed, Cell A1 is a header field and the rest of row 1 is unpopulated. The remaining rows have data

Comment: How is the file generated?  I'd start there...

Comment: Its created by a human, no code generates this file

Answer (score -1):

So you have a comma separated `.csv` file:

[image: comma separated csv]

It looks like this in the Notepad:

[image: Notepad look]

It looks like this in the Excel:

[image: Excel look]

One way to remove the trailing commas is to save the file as `Text (Tab Delimited)(*.txt)` or `Text (MS-DOS)(*.txt)` in Excel:

[image: Save as Text]

which will look like this in Notepad:

[image: New Notepad look]

You can change the file extension from `.txt` to `.csv` and it will not alter the result.